# Разделить текст на две части

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Допустим есть вводимый текст : `'vasya@mail.ru'`

Надо записать все знаки после `'@'` в отдельную переменную.

Типа:

```
count = 'mail.ru'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
email = 'vasya@mail.ru'
username, domain = email.split('@')
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда есть строка, в которой есть несколько символов `'@'`, а нужно разбить только по первому встретившемуся разделителю, удобно использовать метод `partition`:

```
>>> mail = 'vasya@mail.ru'

>>> mail.partition('@')
('vasya', '@', 'mail.ru')

>>> left_part, separator, right_part = mail.partition('@')
```

Аналогично, если нужно отделить самую правую часть по разделителю, для этого есть метод `rpartition`:

```
>>> 'archive.tar.gz'.rpartition('.')
('archive.tar', '.', 'gz')
```